# What font will this preamble create?

Tags: fonts

I was given a template and I am interested in font will this results:

Here is the preamble of the document for LaTex:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
```

I am sorry if this is too basic for this forum, but I am only starting to learn LaTex

Comment: Why don't you simply try it? `:-)`

Comment: CTAN is your friend. [https://ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo?lang=en](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathpazo?lang=en)

Comment: @campa I did compile it.  But how do I tell which font is it? Is there a tool for this?

Answer (score 3):

If you type `texdoc mathpazo` at a command prompt, open the pdf file in a suitable browser, and proceed to section 5, entitled "The package mathpazo", you'll find the following information:

---

[image]

---

Comment: Thank you so much. What are virtual fonts?

Comment: @Boby - May I suggest you google "virtual font latex" in a web browser and click on [What are virtual fonts? The TeX FAQ](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-virtualfonts).